# Logging entries in CenOs?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, logs

I finds suspected files sometimes in /tmp folder and my malware detection clean it.
however I wanted to find out who upload these files and which script and user accounts been used for it.
Is there a way to create a log file continuously log the entries to /tmp folder only with the ip and access time for every files placed in the folder?

I have tried looking for entries in all other existing logs, but the entries are not be found in any of the log files.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the audit subsystem to find out who's creating files in /tmp. First make sure the audit daemon (auditd) is running:

```
# service auditd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  auditd.service
● auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-08-30 03:43:01 EDT; 2 days ago
```

Then add a rule to monitor writes to the /tmp directory (which are file create, delete and rename):

```
# auditctl -w /tmp -p w -k "tmp"
```

This creates a watch on the directory /tmp and logs all writes to the audit log. Logs are in /var/log/audit - you can grep for "tmp" to find all the entries.

Comment: yes. the audit is running..
# service auditd status
auditd (pid  1777) is running...

Comment: The log files are growing fast and there are only 5 files exist, so the info will be updated and gone quickly. I need to find a way to save more log file entries..

Comment: I have set-up to rotate 10 log files, and waiting for a bait ;)